# Cesium: Having the camera in an entity's first person view

Tags: camera, cesiumjs

I would like to have my camera follow the first-person view of a moving entity.  I do not believe that `trackedEntity` will work for this use case because I don't want to look *at* the entity, but I want to look *out* from it.  I would also like the user to be able to use the mouse to turn the camera with respect to the moving entity (for example, to look out the left window of a moving plane).

In a traditional game engine, I would do this by attaching the camera to the entity, so it would move with it, but retain its own local transform with respect to the entity so that it was free to move with respect to the entity.

The only way I can think of right now is to keep track of the "user-controlled" transform separately and multiply it with the entity transform at every clock tick.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Cesium's [Cardboard sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Cardboard.html). Here you are on board of a hot-air balloon and perceive the world from there. After scrolling out, you can pan with the mouse to look around. Since the calculations are quite complicated, I cannot give any details how it works, but it seems that the camera view is aligned to the moving direction of the entity. The essential part of the script is:

```
// Set initial camera position and orientation to be when in the model's reference frame.
var camera = viewer.camera;
camera.position = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
camera.direction = new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
camera.up = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
camera.right = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);

viewer.scene.postUpdate.addEventListener(function (scene, time) {
  var position = entity.position.getValue(time);
  if (!Cesium.defined(position)) {
    return;
  }

  var transform;
  if (!Cesium.defined(entity.orientation)) {
    transform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(position);
  } else {
    var orientation = entity.orientation.getValue(time);
    if (!Cesium.defined(orientation)) {
      return;
    }

    transform = Cesium.Matrix4.fromRotationTranslation(
      Cesium.Matrix3.fromQuaternion(orientation),
      position
    );
  }

  // Save camera state
  var offset = Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(camera.position);
  var direction = Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(camera.direction);
  var up = Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(camera.up);

  // Set camera to be in model's reference frame.
  camera.lookAtTransform(transform);

  // Reset the camera state to the saved state so it appears fixed in the model's frame.
  Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(offset, camera.position);
  Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(direction, camera.direction);
  Cesium.Cartesian3.clone(up, camera.up);
  Cesium.Cartesian3.cross(direction, up, camera.right);
});
```

Maybe you can try to modify the camera vectors or multiply the transform with another rotation matrix to simulate turning one's head (to look left/right/back) while being in the initial perspective. For instance, you can try to combine the example above with code from a  repository called [Cesium First Person Camera Controller](https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJsFirstPersonCameraController).

Answer (score 0):

Had to figure this out myself as well.

[`Camera.setView`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#setView) and self-defined utility functions are your friend.
E.g. Here is a naive implementation of rotation (does not work well when the pitch of the camera is too "birds-eye-view" like):

```
Cesium.Camera.prototype.rotateView = function(rotation) {
    let { heading, pitch, roll } = rotation;
    heading = this.heading + (heading || 0);
    pitch = this.pitch + (pitch || 0);
    roll = this.roll + (roll || 0);
    const destination = this.position;
    this.setView({
        destination,
        orientation: {
            heading,
            pitch,
            roll
    }
  });
};
```

Similarly you can update the position with the position of the entity by providing `destination`.